# Checking url availability

Tags: c#

In my program,I check that a site is available or not, I use this code

```
 HttpWebRequest request;
 HttpWebResponse response;
 Message = string.Empty;
 string result="";

 request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 request.Timeout = 300000;
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
 try
 {

      response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
      result = response.StatusCode.ToString();
      response.Close();

 }
catch (Exception ex)
 {

         result = ex.Message;
 }
```

I set timeout to 5 min. when the program runs,for some sites(Urls) , result is "unable to connect to remote server" but site is available. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you give us an example of such a website?

Answer (score 0):

Some sites have throttles to limit web requests from robots or client with invalid [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) or not recognized string.

Therefore I suggest that you adjust the user agent to a known browser.

For example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
// Mozilla 2.2
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201");

// Safari 7.0.3
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A");
```

For a complete list of user agent string, check out: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php